# MyBatis use different database according to configuration

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm using SpringBoot and MyBatis (using mapper XML) to build an application. Assume there's such a query:

```
SELECT ... FROM some_database.some_table WHERE ...
```

in which `some_database` could change in different "environments" (like `project` or `project_cloud`). By this time, to build artifacts for different "environments", we have to `grep` in our XML files. I wonder if there's a best practice to such circumstance.

*AFAIK, for JPA, one may configure data sources with `application.yml` so that they may refer to "databases" with data source names, instead of actual data base names. I wonder if there's such an option for MyBatis.*

Comment: What is the exact point in naming your db schemas differently in different environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to achieve this is by using MyBatis configuration properties (https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties), e.g.

**application.yml**

```yaml
mybatis:
  ...
  configuration-properties:
    dbschema: project
```

**application-cloud.yml**

```yaml
mybatis:
  ...
  configuration-properties:
    dbschema: project_cloud
```

**SomeMapper.xml**

```xml
...
<select id="getWhateverById" resultMap="...">
    select ...
    from ${dbschema}.some_table
    where ...
</select>
```

The configuration in `application.yml` will be active by default while `application-cloud.yml` will override it when the app is run with the `cloud` profile active.

Make sure to have the `org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter` dependency in your project (https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).

Comment: When I tried this, MyBatis told me that `Parameter 'dbschema' not found, Available parameters are ...`.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it: I'm using MyBatisPlus and it seems that it "proxified" these MyBatis configurations. Now I configure these items in "MyBatisPlus section" and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

### solution1 intercepter

create an intercepter, like SchemaInterceptAnnotation, and you can change the actual sql at runtime.

according to https://javamana.com/2022/04/202204070748273889.html

```
@SchemaInterceptAnnotation(schemaType = "business")
public interface UserMapper {}
```

### solution2 jdbctemplate !!!not mybatis-related

#### two application.yaml files

application.yaml

```
user_db:
  jdbc:mysql://xxx.com:3306/user?characterEncoding=utf8
```

application_product.yaml

```
user_db:
  jdbc:mysql://xxx.com:3306/user_product?characterEncoding=utf8
```

#### switch environment

provide spring.config.name on command line when starting the server

#### register datasource

register all datasource in a map, and give the PO a dataSource config, and when you querying, you get the dataSource out of the map.

```
@Data
@Table(value="table_user", dataSource="user_db")
public class UserPO implements Serializable {
    @DBColumn
    private Long id;
}
```